# Kivy on Raspberry PI : Correct way to unschedule an event

Tags: python, arduino, kivy

Here I'm reading data from Arduino through serial port, the Arduino is constantly sending data at baudrate of 9600. the data send is something like "AGVtoUPF" for a few tens seconds and then the next data for few tens seconds etc.

I need to trigger different event according to the data I received.

What I observe here is the data I receive is correct and fast when there's nothing scheduled. But when one of the schedule is triggered, I got delay in receiving data (eg. Arduino is sending the next data but Kivy still showing the last data for ~3 seconds, a HUGE delay!!).

I'm not sure if it's because I'm scheduling/unschedule the events in a wrong way or is the fps of kivy couldn't catch up the baud rate when something is scheduled.

Here's the code where the schedule/unschedule are happening

```
class OperationScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(OperationScreen,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.Read,1.0/60.0)


    def Read(self,dt):
        data = arduino.readline()
        if data =='':
            pass
        if data != '' and data != self.ids.data_label.text:
            self.ids.data_label.text = data
            if data == 'AGVtoUPFt\r\n':
                print("1")
                Clock.schedule_interval(self.ids.upf.transfer,1.75)
                Clock.schedule_interval(self.ids.agvin.transfer,1.75)
            elif data =='AGVtoUPFv\r\n':
                print("2")
                Clock.schedule_interval(self.ids.upf.vacuum,1.75)
            elif data =='AGVtoUPFvi\r\n':
                print("3")
                Clock.schedule_interval(self.ids.upf.vacin,1.75)
            elif data =='AGVtoUPFi\r\n':
                print("4")
                Clock.schedule_interval(self.ids.upf.inert,1.75)            
            else:
                Clock.unschedule(self.ids.agvin.transfer)
                Clock.unschedule(self.ids.upf.inert)
                Clock.unschedule(self.ids.upf.transfer)
                Clock.unschedule(self.ids.upf.vacuum)
                Clock.unschedule(self.ids.upf.vacin)
```

I did the if/else case this way because I don't want the same event get triggered twice.

I've tried to declare an event like `event_trigger = ObjectProperty(None)` under `class OperationScreen(Screen)` , then do `event_trigger = Clock.schedule_interval(self.ids.agvin.transfer)` on `__init__`, so I can directly use `event_trigger()` and `event_trigger.cancel()` down in the if/else case for schedule/unscheduling

But somehow it gives error when I'm doing `event_trigger = Clock.schedule_interval(self.ids.agvin.transfer)`. So I come out with the method above, I saw on Kivy documentation not recommend using  `Clock.unschedule(self.ids.agvin.transfer)`, is this the reason causing such delay in my program?

Please advice if anyone know anything about it.

Please tell me if I have to provide more information too!

Thanks in advance!!

***UPDATE***

As suggested, I've change my scheduling method, here's my new code

```
class OperationScreen(Screen):
    event_read = ObjectProperty(None)
    upf_transfer = ObjectProperty(None)
    agv_trigger = ObjectProperty(None)
    upf_vacuum = ObjectProperty(None)
    upf_vacin = ObjectProperty(None)
    upf_inert = ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(OperationScreen,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.event_read = Clock.schedule_interval(self.Read,1.0/60.0)
        self.event_read()

    def Read(self,dt):
        data = arduino.readline()
        if data =='':
            pass
        if data != '' and data != self.ids.data_label.text:
            self.ids.data_label.text = data
            if data == 'AGVtoUPFt\r\n':
                print("1")
                self.agv_trigger = Clock.schedule_interval(self.ids.agvin.transfer,1.75)
                self.agv_trigger()
                self.upf_transfer = Clock.schedule_interval(self.ids.upf.transfer,1.75)
                self.upf_transfer()

            elif data =='AGVtoUPFv\r\n':
                print("2")
                self.upf_vacuum = Clock.schedule_interval(self.ids.upf.vacuum,1.75)
                self.upf_vacuum()
            elif data =='AGVtoUPFtvi\r\n':
                print("3")
                self.upf_vacin = Clock.schedule_interval(self.ids.upf.vacin,1.75)
                self.upf_vacin()
            elif data =='AGVtoUPFti\r\n':
                print("4")
                self.upf_inert = Clock.schedule_interval(self.ids.upf.inert,1.75)
                self.upf_inert()
            else:
                Clock.unschedule(self.agv_trigger)
                Clock.unschedule(self.upf_inert)
                Clock.unschedule(self.upf_vacin)
                Clock.unschedule(self.upf_vacuum)
                Clock.unschedule(self.upf_transfer)
```

But the delay in receiving data is still there, and it only occurs when I have animation going on, please help.

Comment: According to the `Clock` [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html#unscheduling), `Calling CyClockBase.unschedule() on the original callback is highly discouraged because it’s significantly slower than when using the event.` Perhaps you should be saving references to the scheduled events, and using that for unscheduling.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the scheduling or trigger to an attribute e.g.

## [Creating Trigger Event](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html#triggered-events)

```
self.event_trigger = Clock.create_trigger(self.ids.agvin.transfer, 1.75)
```

## [Scheduling Event](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html)

```
self.event_trigger()
self.event_read = Clock.schedule_interval(self.Read,1.0/60.0)
```

## [Unschedule Event](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html#unscheduling)

```
Clock.unschedule(self.event_trigger)
Clock.unschedule(self.event_read)
```

or

```
self.event_trigger.cancel()
self.event_read.cancel()
```

## Reference

[Kivy Clock Object](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did some update on my code, but the problem still persists

Comment: I came across this free only clock from your link. Will changing the scheduling for ``Read`` function to free_only clock help? if yes please help as I have no idea how to do that